# jQuery .click to toggle div content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have the following div to display a certain result

```
<div id="results">
        <span id="eresult">0</span>|
        <span id="gresult">0</span>|
        <span id="aresult">0</span>|
        <span id="presult">0</span>|
        <span id="vpresult">0</span>
    </div>
```

However, I would like to toggle the visibility when I click on the following input button:

```
<input id="rbu" type="image" src="toggle.png" width="50" height="50">
```

This is my jQuery

```
$("#rbu").click(function () {
    $("#results").toggle();
});
```

The div does disappear when clicked but it does not appear again. How do I make it show again?

Comment: Works [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/orn4L94j/) for me

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or snippet so we can test it? As @JCOC611 says, the code itself looks fine, so this may come from other components of your pages (other JS code, CSS, etc.)

Comment: Your code is working properly

Comment: Thanks everyone, apparently it was a mistake elsewhere after looking through it multiple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with Chrome, without any change in your code:

```js
$("#rbu").click(function () {
    $("#results").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">
  <span id="eresult">0</span>|
  <span id="gresult">0</span>|
  <span id="aresult">0</span>|
  <span id="presult">0</span>|
  <span id="vpresult">0</span>
</div>

<input id="rbu" type="image" src="toggle.png" width="50" height="50">
```

The error may be elsewhere in your code, try to clean it ?

Comment: Without any __major__ or __any__ change?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$("#rbu").click(function () {
    if($("#results").is(':hidden')) $("#results").show();
    else $("#results").hide();
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

dont use .click - if your dom changed, it doesnt work anymore..  try .on method:

```
$("#rbu").on('click', function() {
    $("#results").toggle();
});
```

if #rbu is a link or button with own listeners (events) , try this:

```
$("#rbu").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#results").toggle();
});
```